# Helper method from application_controller not accessible from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helpermethods

Application controller has a helper methods : current_user is accessible from all my views. But pro_user is completely inaccessible from my view.

```
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token( cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
    helper_method :current_user

   def pro_user

        @pro_user ||= Subscription.where(:email => current_user.email).pluck(:email) 
        return @pro_user
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

   end
   helper_method :pro_user
```

Now in the view, if i access pro_user its always nil. But funnily I have a method called current_user also in the application controller which is a helper_method. It's working fine in the view.

Please can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand the use-case of your query, `Subscription.where(:email => current_user.email).pluck(:email)`? When you already have the **`current_user.email`** why to pluck the *same email* from `subscriptions` table by firing the query?

Comment: Kirti current_user.email gets stored in Subscription table after user successfully purchases. pro_user method is below the current_user method in the application controller to check if user is a premium aka pro_user. In the view I was trying to see if pro_user.email.blank? and its nil all the time. I also tried @pro_user in the view. Everything prints correctly in the application controller but its nil in the view.

Comment: Kirti, you have helped me 2 times before alread! So I am hoping you can shed some light into this again :)

Comment: Your method is accessible in the view, the problem is with the query which is returning 0 records. You need to figure out *why Subscription records were not saved for current_user*. Follow meager's answer. He has given a thorough explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your'e misdiagnosing your problem. It's working just fine, and the view can definitely see your method, but your method is returning `nil`. Your method isn't returning anything.

If the method actually weren't accessible, you'd see an exception to that effect. Ruby doesn't simply resolve unknown methods to `nil`.

> In the view I was trying to see if pro_user.email.blank? and its nil all the time.

That isn't a valid way of using the value returned by the method you posted. It returns an array.

> I also tried @pro_user in the view. Everything prints correctly in the application controller but its nil in the view.

Neither is that. The method returns an array of zero or more email addresses, this is what `pluck` does is for. The return value will never respond to `.email`. You would need to use `pro_email.any?` to test whether the array contains any items.

You also can't simply access `@pro_user`. That doesn't invoke the method, that access a member variable which *will* be `nil` by default.

> I do <% if pro_user.blank? %> { ..do blah.. }

That's not valid erb syntax. Assuming that your syntax is actually correct, `blank?` will return `true` for an empty array. The method is returning `[]`, not `nil`. There is no error, you just need to figure out why your query returns zero records.

Comment: I removed the recuse statement and added return @pro_user at the end of the method. Still no use.

Comment: @user2511030 How are you invoking the method?

Comment: In the view : I do <% if pro_user.blank? %> { ..do blah.. }

Comment: meagar do you mean i have to do pro_user.any? What i a having difficulty with is the current_user method which is very similar to pro_user is accessible in all my views. I can do @current_user, current_user.email in all the views and it works beautifully.

Comment: meagar, yes it will return [] if the user is not a pro user and return ["user@email.com"] if successfully payment was received. So i have been doing .blank? empty? nil? on the pro_user in the view. I will try .any?